# Performance test system for training

Tags: performance-analysis

I'm searching a system that could be used for performance test training, since I will run a workshop on performance test and would like to use the system, if available, for performance counter analysis & troubleshooting, hotspot analysis, thread dump analysis and how to fix it.

No OS restriction but one must be free. I just want a system that has some obvious bottleneck which could be easily fixed so this would be better.

I tried to Google but no such system was found. Wonder if there's bright idea here or enlighten me. Thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! There might be such a thing. It would help if you could give some more details on your requirements, e.g.: on what OS it should run, what do you want to performance test, what is your price margin, etc. There are quite different requirements for performance testing say, a database, a specific application, or a website, so I'd assume the same is valid for corresponding training suites (which additionally might need to match the testing software you want to train).

Comment: Izzy, thanks for your reply. The requirement is simple, no OS restriction but one must be free. I just want a system that has some obvious bottleneck which could be easily fixed so this would be better.

Comment: And by "free" you mean as in "free beer" (no costs) or as in "free speech" (FOSS)?